# cmdow and keyboard focus

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard, focus

cmdow utility running on Windows NT and windows 10

I run a bat file from a cmd window started from a directory comprising my jpg photo files.

The bat file lists all the jpg files and creates another bat file. This new bat file is then 'called' from within the current bat file :

```
echo off
del /Q annotateAll.bat
for /r %%f in (*.jpg) do (
   echo call annotatepics.bat "%%~nxf" >> annotateAll.bat
)
call annotateAll.bat
del /Q annotateAll.bat
```

In annotatepics.bat I call (amongst other image manipulations)

```
  set img=%~nx1%
  magick convert "%img%" -thumbnail 300x200 win:
```

Because calling the above magick function creates a window, the focus goes there, but I want the focus to remain in my cmd window so I can type in a title for the jpg image just displayed

```
set /p ptext=Photo Title ?
```

I have had partial success calling

```
cmdow imdisplay* /INA
```

(imdisplay is the name of the window created by magick)

and then

```
  cmdow @ /TOP
  cmdow @ /ACT
```

where @ is the current cmd window where I want the keyboard focus.

The issue are

- on NT and 10 the cmdow imdisplay* /INA inactivates OK but then
  activates some other (usually unrelated) window which, if iconized,
  opens and blots out my preferred windows).
- The cmdow @ /TOP and /ACT works most of the time on NT (by working I
  mean that the       keyboard focus goes to the cmd window so I can
  type in a title for       the picture) but on Windows 10 the cmd
  window is active alright but      it does not have keyboard focus. So
  I have to click in it to get the     keyboard focus.

My questions are :

- (discussion) why is 'activating' a window using cmdow not the same as
  getting keyboard focus in it (particularly on windows 10)
- there's no cmdow @ /FOC  (or similar argument) to get the focus in a
  window - but is there a sequence of cmdow commands that will do the
  same? (I did try iconizing and restoring - this works on NT but not
  10)
- are these issues because I'm calling bat files from within other bat
  files?

Comment: I do not know Magick, but perhaps [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) could help for the current window to not lose the focus: `start "" /MIN magick convert "%~nx1" -thumbnail 300x200 win:`

Comment: You `call annotateAll.bat` but in `annotateAll.bat` you simply run `annotatepics.bat` which usually would break the call/return stack? Where does the window imdisplay* stem from? In which file is the `set /p`? As for cmdow, the author Ritchie Lawrence is IIRC also a SO user.

Comment: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\windows\notepad.exe""", 7, false` put in a VBS file. You can use 4, 7, and 8 to avoid activation and 0 hides it. None are ideal. This line changes foreground window `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Notepad - Untitled"`

Comment: aschipfl : The start command certainly prevented the initial cmd window from losing focus.. until the point that the magick program created it's own IMDisplay window to display the jpg image - then windows assigned focus to that window :( I was back to reselecting the cmd window.

Comment: LotPings : Apologies, I DO actually 'call' the annotatepics.bat each time in the annotateAll.bat file - I'll correct my original post. The imdisplay* is the id of the window (showing the jpg image). It is created by the magick program and I found the id by using the cmdow /t  option. This is how cmdow can identify windows (one of the ways, anyway). So with this Id I can move and resize the IMDisplay window - and inactivate it also. The set /p is in the black windows cmd window created by the original bat file. I want to type a string there to annotate the jpg image. I want the focus here.

Comment: Noodles : VB could be a good way to go. I'll have a look at that. What I found surprising was that cmdow /ACT will happily activate a window but actually putting the keyboard focus there was a different matter - especially on Windows 10.

Comment: @mike, to reply to a certain comment, precede the related user name with a `@` symbol (and omit any spaces), like I did hereby; so the user is going to be notified...

Comment: There are rules about activating windows. Putting a window at the front is not the same as activating it. The rules are detailed here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx